# Sending email from SSRS 2005 report

Tags: email, reporting-services

I have a report generated using SSRS 2005. It contains multiple pages where each page has a specific employee information, including email address. User would like to click on the button located at the report header to send an email to every person on this report with his / her personal information page attached.
Any help will be truly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cant send an email from a executed report. The only way to send a report by email is creating a [Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)